# GridView vs DataGrid Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, gridview, binding, datagrid

I always had major performance problems when setting .ItemsSource on a Datagrid to a collection. The method returns fast, but there is a very noticable delay before anything is actually rendered to the screen. Since the Datagrid has the Virtualization modes set, it should be able to handle very larges collections easily. I printed out some debug information in the binded properties of the item collection, to make sure it's not loading the whole collection, but it only accessed the first few items, so I'm sure virtualization is working. And even for small collections, the delay is about the same, so it seems unrelated to actual data loading.

So it's purely the rendering that is causing the slowdown. Most of the times this is caused by having the Datagrid inside a ScrollViewer, or having auto row-height generation, etc. But I ruled all these possible causes out, by giving everything fixed width's, and make sure nothing is set to 'Infinite' or 'Auto'.

After pulling my hair out for weeks, I tried something simple: I switched the Datagrid for a GridView. And to my amazement it does not suffer from the large delay, it paints instantly. Both have exactly the same properties and styling, so I'm trying to understand why the Datagrid was so much slower.

Is there any logical reason why a DataGrid could be slower than a GridView?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the number of properties, events, and methods.  DataGrid has an edit template.   DataGrid is just a much heavier weight control and GridView was built for speed.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` is always going to be quite slow, but you can get a (fairly) significant performance boost by using the `EnableRow/ColumnVirtualization` properties to true (not sure if you are doing this already) and setting a fixed column width as it causes fewer re-calculations of the layout to be performed.

Suggestions taken from [here](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/04/25/wpf-datagrid-performance-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank Yoy, Grid view is the best I look for. 
I have many problems with data grid.
there is a very high memory leak in datagrid. when you update datagrid many times, the UI thread becomes slower and slower until software crash.
but gridview is very high performance
.
Thank you